# How to call a set phone number from a button click using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Hello I am working on a app that needs to call a certain phone number when the button is clicked i am using Xamarin iOS to do this here's my code:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace appname
{
    partial class HomeView : UIViewController
    {

        public HomeView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            phonebutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                var url = new NSUrl("tel:12345678");
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
            };
        } 
    }
}
```

I am new to Xamarin iOS so any links of examples would be so amazing!

Answer (score 0):

This code seems correct to me - have you tried to test it on a device?

Comment: yes when the app launches I get this error message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: @Phoneswapshop Have you tried to check the stacktrace of the exception?